# How to use canvas even listeners in Salesforce Lightning

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I want to use canvas event listeners in Salesforce Lightning. Below is my Java script code

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousedrag",handleEvent,true);
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",handleEvent,true);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",handleEvent,true);
window.addEventListener("mouseup",handleEvent,true);
```